# resize header image to fit the browser automatically

Tags: css, header

so here I have a header image like below

[image]

i planned to make stretch the header image to 100% for the monitor resolution, what's the best practice and way to achieve this? i've tried to do this:

```
.LippoHeader
{
background-image: url('../images/body/headerpng_BG.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
width: 100%;
height: 170px;
}
.shadowone
{
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: -1px;
top: 172px;
display: inline-block;
}
.shadowtwo
{
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: -1px;
top: 173px;
display: inline-block;
}
.shadowthree
{
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: -1px;
top: 176px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

it still can't stretch to 100% fit into monitor (it only stretch as the image resolution itself allow) unless i add:

> position: absolute;

is there anyway to do this? if possible i wouldn't want to add that, i was told to not set the position to absolute, because it's a bad practice

here's the screen capture of the header:
[image]

also i used master page, so no body tag, only div tag, i used .ascx for my panel header, my code is

```
<div class="LippoHeader">
  <div>
    <img src="images/body/shadow.png" class="shadowone" />
    <img src="images/body/shadow.png" class="shadowtwo" />
    <img src="images/body/shadow.png" class="shadowthree" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're not using a `body` tag?

Comment: the body tag in is the master page, i used .ascx for the header and footer

Comment: Ah, so from the new code I see that you want to overlay three images on top of a background image?  With the background image taking up the full width?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i'm trying to tell, hahaha. is it possible to do it? or i should come up with another way?

Comment: How should those 3 overlay images be placed?

Comment: Can you link to the site or the full stylesheet?  The `body` tag might have a width set on it.

Comment: the 3 overlay images will be just slightly below the header, for the shadow effect of the image, the full css: http://jsfiddle.net/abiegiordano/gJwqG/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34211/discussion-between-hungerstar-and-abie-giordano)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to repeat an image and have a `div` take up the whole width of the browser window and not an actual individual image you will want to make sure there is no margin on the `html` or `body` tags. Looking at the supplied jsFiddle you will want to remove the margin.

```css
html,
body {
     margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you want to stretch the header, not the image itself; the image is being repeated horizontally.

I treated `LippoHeader` as a div and it worked with no problems in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mst5g/). However, it doesn't take 100% of the monitor's width, but 100% of its parent's width (in this example, `body`). Was this your goal?

Comment: yes, i mean that, but in my case it still doesn't fill in 100% of the page width, please see my edit